# Getting error while access Private PAIR Tools

Tags: uspto, provisional-application, pair

I'm trying to check my provisional patent status through Private PAIR tool and keep getting following error page after logged in.

I uploaded my patent application through https://efs.uspto.gov/EFSWebUIUnregistered/EFSWebUnregistered  and made the payment online when it redirected to their new portal. I had registered on MyUSPTO this whole time and used the same email address in the online form.

I can still login into Patent Center app, but can't see or search by application id. And it gives me above error in Private PAIR.

- How can I get it working ?
- Is there any other way to check my provisional patent status ?

[image: Private PAIR page after logged in]

Comment: I don't have an answer, but it might be helpful if you specified the computer's operating system and which browser you are using.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10 OS and Chrome Version 103.0.5060.66. The same happen on Firefox browser. So I don't think this has something to do with that.

Comment: Based on a google search, okta may be used for ID services. I think you’ll need to contact USPTO.

Comment: Already did and waiting for their reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From USPTO [site](https://www.uspto.gov/patents/apply/filing-online/new-users/access-unsuccessful)

> To access EFS-Web for registered eFilers and Private PAIR, you must have a verified USPTO.gov account.  New customers, or customers who did not migrate by the migration deadline, can obtain a verified USPTO.gov account using the new [verification process](https://www.uspto.gov/patents/apply/applying-online/getting-started-new-users).

To be readily able to see your application after uploading on the EFSWEB system you *must* use the registered EFSWEB not the unregistered EFSWEB. To do that you need to already have a customer number that is used when you file. That is not the same as having an account with the USPTO. The customer number is what connects you and the right to see your application.

You will need to get a customer number and then you can call the USPTO and give them sufficient information about your application so they can attach it to your customer number.

A MyUSPTO account isn’t the same thing.

It is possible you do have a customer number but if you used unregistered EFSWEB it didn’t get associated with you application.

Call the EFS help line 1-866-217-9197. They are open late and are very helpful.

Also, Public PAIR is being retired at the end of July 2022. Private PAIR will still be available but you might want to move to the more modern [PatentCenter](https://patentcenter.uspto.gov/).

Comment: I have checked in the Public Pair but it can't find my provisional patent status. I can't find an option to check the status in the Patent Center application.

Comment: Only the applicant can see their application until it is published. Public PAIR is for the public and they can’t see unpublished things. Provisional’s are never “published “ but become visible to the public if and when an application that claims priority from it is published.  To see your provisional in patent center or private PAIR you need a patent center account and a customer number and your application needed to be filed with your customer number. Otherwise how are you different from the public in regards to “your” application. They need a way to know you are the actual applicant .

Comment: I have already submitted my provisional patent through https://efs.uspto.gov/EFSWebUIUnregistered/EFSWebUnregistered this online form and made the payment online when it redirected to their new portal. I had registered on MyUSPTO this whole time and used the same email address in the online form. I can still login into Patent Center app, but can't see or search by application id. And it gives me above error in Private PAIR.

Comment: Rather than have this dialog in comments I have put this crucial information into your question and edited my answer based on it.

Answer (score 1):

As per USPTO office there two three steps needs to be done to get full access to Private PAIR.

1. Create a USPTO.gov account
2. Obtain a Customer Number
3. Obtain a Verified USPTO.gov Account

https://www.uspto.gov/patents/apply/applying-online/getting-started-new-users

Comment: You have answered your own question which is fine since it is an answer. It is also correct. You need a customer number.

Comment: Yes George, my issue was I just had created my account and didn't follow the remaining steps. Anyway USPTO web application is showing a technical level error message instead of meaningful user error message.